# Create new column based on data type and shift data there

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in this form:

```
Name      Value
Car         10
Train        X
Plane    01-01-2010
Ship         Y
```

I want to create new columns and shift data based on type:

```
Name      Integer  Date       Category
Car           10    NaN          NaN 
Train        NaN    NaN            X
Plane        NaN   01-01-2010    NaN
Ship         NaN    NaN            Y
```

Comment: You could do something like `df.pivot`, by the value of `df.dtypes`. On SO you're required to make an attempt to code it yourself and post that, it's not allowed to just post a spec and ask people to give you the code. Show us which commands you tried, and what happened.

Comment: By the way, don't use the word 'shift', that means 'get lagged series'. I'd call what you're doing 'transform' (long-to-wide), 'reshape' or 'pivot'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the "Value" column's type to str, and make a df with regex. Then you would have to rename columns and change their types back.

```
re_int = r'[A-Za-z]|(\d-\d-\d)'
re_letter = r'(^((?!\D).)*$)|(\d-\d-\d)'
re_date = r'(^((?!\D).)*$)|[A-Za-z]'

def nanify(df, regex):
  return(df.replace(regex, np.NaN, regex=True))

dfv = df.Value.astype(str)
df = pd.concat([df.Name, nanify(dfv, re_int), nanify(dfv, re_date), 
                nanify(dfv, re_date)], axis=1)
```

There might be a simpler way to do this with DataFrame.where().